# Integral of exponential of Shannon Entropy Function

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-analysis, information-theory, entropy

Here I am going to ask a similar question as [rde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255450/approximation-of-shannon-entropy-by-trigonometric-functions) asked , that is what is the integral of exponential of entropy function. That is what is the value of

$$F[H(x)]=\int_{-1}^{+1} e^{ikH(f(x^2))} dx$$

where $H(x)=-x\operatorname{Log}_2(x)-(1-x)\operatorname{Log}_2(1-x)$ and $f_0$ and $f$ are linear function of type $ax+b$

More generally, what I want is the integral if $x=\cos(\theta)$ then

$\int_{-1}^{1} e^{ikf_0(x^2)H(f(x^2))}d(x)$
where $f_0\neq f(x)$

Comment: What interval is that integral over?

Comment: I have edited the question a bit @QiaochuYuan, with updated integrals

Comment: Your question looks to me a little localized, poorly motivated and with some bad or poor notation (you state properties of $f_0$ before using it, $x = \cos \theta$ is out of context and irrelevant, etc).